# IAM Role not getting applied to Auto Scaling group Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Below is a brief summary of my problem :

I have an EC2 instance which has a particular role (with a custom policy for accessing a S3 bucket). From this instance I've created an AMI, created a Launch configuration (with this AMI) and an Auto Scaling group for the same. However when the Auto Scaling group instances are created, they don't have this role attached to them by default.

Is there anything which I need to check for ? FYI please note below:

1. There is an "IAM Instance profile" on the Launch configuration where I can temporarily apply IAM roles to the instance during start up. I've tried this option as well, but the role doesn't get applied.
2. When I manually add the role to the ASG instance it works fine. Hence the only issue is getting this role to be added to the ASG instance (when it's starting up).

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: The role should be added in a new launch configuration (can't modify existing LC), and ASG should be set to use the new LC. Have you tried that? This way new  instances  (not existing ones) will use new LC and have the role.

Comment: I believe you're talking about the "IAM Instance Profile" config while creation of an LC. As I've mentioned above I have tried this option , however the ASG instance (from this LC) doesn't get the role attached.

Comment: Can you provide more detaills? Screenshots of your LC and ASG setup?

Answer (score 3):

The IAM Role should be selected in the "IAM Instance Profile" within the Launch Configuration. (An Instance Profile is the mapping between an instance and the Role.)

Please note that **it is not possible to edit a Launch Configuration**. Instead, you will need to:

- Create a **new** Launch Configuration with the desired settings
- **Edit the Auto Scaling group** and change to the new Launch Configuration

Any **new instances** launched in the Auto Scaling group *after* this change will have the new settings. (The settings will *not* update on *existing* instances.)